# JavaFX Wombo Combo-displaying the text depending on the choice from the drop-down list

Tags: java, javafx

How can I display text in a window in the form of eg:

Destination London, discount Senior

I dont know JavaFx well, so I tried to do something like this

```
package sample;

public class Main extends Application {


Stage window;
Scene scene;
Button button;
ComboBox<String> destinationBox, discountBox;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Tickets");


    destinationBox = new ComboBox<>();
    destinationBox.getItems().addAll(
            "Berlin", "London", "Madrid", "Moscow", "Paris", "Prague", "Rome"
    );

    discountBox = new ComboBox<>();
    discountBox.getItems().addAll(
            "Full price", "Senior", "Student"
    );
    discountBox.setValue("Full price");
    destinationBox.setValue("Berlin");
    Label label = new Label("Destination " + destinationBox.getValue() + " " + "discount " + discountBox.getValue());


    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
    layout.getChildren().addAll(label, discountBox, destinationBox);

    scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: `destinationBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()` instead of `destinationBox.getValue()`

Comment: @Abra when using ComboBox there is no need to work with the selection model. Simply "listen" to the value property.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing missing is the piece of code that "reacts" to changes of the value properties of those two combo boxes. Try adding this:

```
StringBinding binding = Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "Destination " + destinationBox.getValue() + " " + "discount " + discountBox.getValue(), destinationBox.valueProperty(), discountBox.valueProperty());
Label label = new Label();
label.textProperty().bind(binding);
```